# RegEx replacing IMG src attributes

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-7

I have a `var baseURL` that I know is: `baseURL = c:\whatever\mybasedir\`
I have an HTML source code that may contain this:

```
<IMG alt="foo" src="file://c:\whatever\mybasedir\root\foo\bla.gif">
or/and:
<IMG alt="foo" src="file://c:/whatever/mybasedir/root/foo/bla.gif">
or/and:
<IMG src="c:\whatever\mybasedir\root\foo\bla.gif">
or/and: 
<IMG src="c:\whatever\mybasedir/root/foo/bla.gif">
```

I need to replace all src tags so that result path is Unix style relative to `baseURL`:

```
<IMG src="root/foo/bla.gif">
```

or if there was an alt attribute (or other. order of attributes may vary):

```
<IMG alt="foo" src="root/foo/bla.gif">
```

How do I match `<IMG * src="*" *>`?
Any ideas what RegEx (or other method) can help here?

(I cannot use DOM to do this job, since the IE8/9 DOM is causing this situation in the first place - automatically adding `<base href>` to all relative src tags)

Comment: Always worth consulting @bobince at moments like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, That was funny :D How can I use XML parser on HTML? (not XHTML)

Comment: Well, you need an HTML parser for this job. Of course, regex may do what you need. As an aside, today I happen to be wearing my Stack Overflow T-shirt that contains the text of bobince's famous answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

Regex: `(<IMG[^>]*)src="[^"]*c:.whatever.mybasedir.`

Replace with:`$1src="`

Comment: I'm always surprised what convoluted patterns you RegEx people can construct +1

Comment: I still need to replace `root\foo\bla.gif` to `root/foo/bla.gif` how can I also match the part after `c:.whatever.mybasedir.`?

Comment: I have changed your RE to `(<IMG[^>]*)src="[^"]*c:.whatever.mybasedir.(.*?")` and used a call-back on `$2` to replace "\" to "/".

Answer (score 3):

Replace `(<IMG.*src=")(.*[/\\])(root[/\\].*?".*>)`

with `$1$3`

**EDIT**

Hope this will work

Replace `(<IMG.*src=")(.*[/\\]mybasedir[/\\])(root)(([/\\][^/\\]+)*)(".*>)`

with `$1$3$4$6`

Comment: I'm always surprised what convoluted patterns you RegEx people can construct +1

Comment: It almost works! but result is (for the first/and third IMG): `src="root\foo\bla.gif"` (backslash) and I need `root/foo/bla.gif"` (slash)

Comment: The task fails if the path already contains `root` e.g. `c:\whatever\root\mybasedir\root\foo\bla.gif`

Comment: So which root should be considered for beginning the path? One following `mybasedir`?

Comment: The "root" is the one following mybasedir. that is correct but the path may already contain "root" (as showed in my comment) - so $3 will match `root\mybasedir\root\foo\bla.gif` in that case.